# Azure Push Notification Hub is not sending notification on Andriod device using FCM V1

Tags: c#, firebase-cloud-messaging, azure-notificationhub

I have created a push notification hub and configured the FCM v1 credentials on Azure hub page.

I'm calling CreateFcmV1TemplateRegistrationAsync to add registration

And SendTemplateNotificationAsync to send the notification to FCM v1 device.

However notifications are not appearing on android device. Registrations in the hub look correct.

Message template used - public const string FcmV1 = "{"message":{"notification":{"title":"$(title)", "body":"$(body)"}}}";

On Matrix hub shows FCM Error, I do have access to other diagnostic logs.
Test send is not working as well. If I send a test notification from firebase itself, it works

Push notification should appear on android devices using FCMv1 and azure notification hub

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.